# Trying to solve a problem using stream API to find the chunk size. Giving error at .collect(Collectors.toList(ArrayList<int[]>::new)). Java 8+ Stream

Tags: arraylist, java-8, coding-style, lightweight-stream-api

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + chunkSize)
            .limit((long) Math.ceil((double) input.length / chunkSize))
            .mapToObj(j -> Arrays.copyOfRange(input, j, j + chunkSize > input.length ? input.length : j + chunkSize))
            .collect(Collectors.toList(ArrayList<int[]>::new));
}
```

I was trying to print array using Java 8 stream and it should return the type List<int[]> to the main function. example input are mentioned in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to create a `List<int[]>`, but the syntax used to create the list is incorrect. To fix this, you can replace the following line:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList(ArrayList<int[]>::new));
```

with this line:

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will create a `List<int[]>` using the default `List` implementation, which is `ArrayList`.

Alternatively, you could specify the `ArrayList` implementation explicitly, like this:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

This will also create a `List<int[]>` using the `ArrayList` implementation.

Comment: You can also specify the list’s element type explicitly, i.e. `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<int[]>::new))`. But the key point is, to use either, `toList()` without arguments or `toCollection(…)` with a factory argument.